# PM2 process manager scheduler

Tags: javascript, pm2

Using PM2 as process manager and having the following `ecosystem.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "a",
      script: "./src/scheduler/jobs/a.js",
      instances: 1,
      watch: ["./src"],
      autorestart: false,
      cron_restart: "0 10,23 * * *",
    },
    {
      name: "b",
      script: "./src/scheduler/jobs/b.js",
      watch: ["./src"],
      instances: 1,
      autorestart: false,
      cron_restart: "0 12,1 * * *",
    },
    {
      name: "c",
      script: "./src/scheduler/jobs/c.js",
      watch: ["./src"],
      instances: 1,
      autorestart: false,
      cron_restart: "0 8,21 * * *",
    },
  ],
};
```

By doing `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` all of them start at the same time without respecting the cron rule. I can't run all of them at the same time because they do operations that are mutually exclusive. My previous and working implementation was one single process that was handling all the cron part. Is there a way to replicate something like that using pm2 and cron_restart/autorestart? The only thing I need is starting them using the cron rule and not immediately. In case, does the solution work when everything is handled by a service at the boot (like systemctl)?

Thanks